# Old Animation/Anime where the protagonist had red spiky hair

Tags: story-identification, anime, animation

I am 23 and I remember as a kid (6-10 yo) watching a videotape animation that had some prob kids (?) with superpowers... I remember only that the protagonist had red spiky hair (like a triangle) and that the whole animation was something like a db ripoff.

Comment: This is way way _way_ too broad. Please look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in.

Comment: Before this was put on hold, I was going to guess Mon Colle Knights.

Answer (score 2):

**D.N.Angel**

[image: ][1]]

[From Official ADV Films website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.N.Angel): "This is the story of a 14 year old boy, Daisuke Niwa, who turns into Phantom Thief Dark when he becomes enamored with a certain local girl that he is fond of. Poor little Daisuke is sucked into this tale of thieving, and the only thing that will return his life to normal is to steal the heart of the woman he loves. Too bad that the object of his affections only has eyes for his other, more dangerous self! Daisuke, or as his alter-ego, Dark steals artwork that have some sort of cursed power and cause troubles for the town and its people. Once the works of art are obtained, their power is sealed by him or his family (Daisuke’s grandfather and mother). "

Original japanese run Date: April 3, 2003 – September 25, 2003